# Reference type v. Value type

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I have a question.  When I do a

```
 Int32 ii = new Int32();
```

am I creating a value type of a reference type with the identifier "ii?"  If I'm creating a reference type, then how is it that when I pass a copy of that reference to a method that changes it's value, I don't see the changes when the method returns?  When I run the code below I get "0."

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Int32 ii = new Int32();

            changeit(ii);
            Console.WriteLine(ii.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        static void changeit (Int32 i) 
        {
            i = 2;
        }

        static void changeit(ref int i)
        {
            i = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new` doesn't change a value type to a reference type.

Comment: Because you're calling the wrong function. Just do `changeit(ref li)` and you'll see the value change.

Comment: @tnw That's passing a value type by reference, not passing a reference type by value, as he is expecting.  It's creating the expected results through an unexpected means, hampering understanding of the relevant concepts.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Every time I think I understand and out I go, it always pulls me back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm creating a reference type

You aren't creating a reference type.  Using `new` doesn't change value type to a reference type.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Int32 ii = new Int32();

        changeit1(ii);
        Console.WriteLine(ii.ToString());
        changeit2(ref ii);
        Console.WriteLine(ii.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static void changeit1(Int32 i) 
    {
        i = 2;
    }

    static void changeit2(ref int i)
    {
        i = 2;
    }
```

Results:

> 0
>
> 2

Answer (score 2):

The new operator has a different meaning for value and reference types. For reference types, it means to allocate on the heap *and* initialize the type; for value types it means initialize only. So

```
int i=new int();
```

is the same as

```
int i=0;
```

See [C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) as a starter.

Answer (score 1):

Int32 is by definition a value type. A type can be a value type or reference type by definition, you can't change it.

If you want your Int32 to be modified, you should pass it with the "ref" keyword:

```
static void changeit(ref int i)
    {
        i = 2;
    }
```

The only way to acomplish something like that is encapsulating your Int32 inside a class, like:

```
public class DumbClass{
  public int YourInt {get; set;}
}
```

When you put your integer as a property, you can change it, sending your DumbClass reference:

```
static void changeit(DumbClass c)
    {
        c.YourInt = 2;
    }
```

This happens because classes are reference types (by definition).

Inside the hood, a lot of things happens. The framework may decide to allocate your variable in the stack or the heap depending os it's mood (because sometimes optimizations happens).

Usually when you declare an int inside a method, it's allocated on the stack and since it will be deallocated when the method finishes it's execution, it will be pretty weird if it is a reference type.

That's why there's the "boxing" and "unboxing" inside the framework. Sometimes value types are "boxed" so you can use it as reference types (and allocated on the managed heap). Personally, I don't know if there's a way to do it explicitly in C# and if it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  This is an awesome explanation.